# I can't stop the CSS glowing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The glowing CSS effect is:

```
//Public Variables.
var clear_interval;
var stop_set_time_out;

function record_css_effect() {
    clear_interval = setInterval(

    function() {
        rec_block.css('background-color', "red");
        stop_set_time_out = setTimeout(function() {
            rec_block.css('background-color', "green");
        }, 500)
    }, 1000);
};
```

And in another function, I call:

```
function stop_record() {
    alert("Stop record.");
    clearTimeout(stop_set_time_out);
    clearInterval(clear_interval);
}​
```

The glowing only stops first time.

The second time, I didn't call `record_css_effect()` function **yet** the glowing effect happened automatically...
which would mean that the `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` don't work...

Why is that, and How can I achieve it?

UPDATE:

Actually, I use **clearInterval( clear_interval );** in many places. 

As the user want to take record,they press on a button, and pop_record_window() is then called.

---

```
function pop_record_window()
{
 $('#start_and_stop_rec').click
 (
    function(){ record_voice(); }
 ) 
}
function record_voice()
{
    record_css_effect();
    REC= $("#start_and_stop_rec");
    if(REC.prop("value")=="record")
    {
        alert("Start to record");           
        alert( dir_path + User_Editime + "/rec"+"/" + "P" + current_page + "_" + records_pages_arr[current_page].get_obj_num() +".mp3");
        current_rec_path= dir_path + User_Editime + "/rec"+"/" + "P" + current_page + "_" + records_pages_arr[current_page].get_obj_num() +".mp3";
        cur_record_file= new Media(current_rec_path,onSuccess, onError);
        cur_record_file.startRecord();  

        $('#stop_rec').bind("click", function(){

            clearTimeout( stop_set_time_out );
            clearInterval( clear_interval ); 

        });

        REC.prop("value","stop");
    }
    else if(REC.prop("value") == "stop")
    {
        stop_record();
        cur_record_file.stopRecord();           

        clearInterval( clear_interval );
        //make visibility hidden!
        REC.prop("value","record");
    }   
};
```

But since the second time, the user didn't press on the button: **start_and_stop_rec**, the glowing effect fires. However, the code within 
if(REC.prop("value")=="record") condition doesn't execute.

Comment: When will you call record_css_effect() function?

Comment: post the part where you actually call the functions

Comment: Maybe you called `record_css_effect` multiple times? Put a call to `stop_record();` into it before starting them (again)

Comment: @Bergi          I call record_css_effect lots of time, but each time after I call that I'll call clearInterval...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `record_css_effect()` multiple times multiple intervals might start but only the last interval-id will be stored in `clear_interval`. By ensuring only 1 interval is running at a time you can prevent this from happening.

```
//Public Variables.
var clear_interval;
var stop_set_time_out;

function record_css_effect() {
    if (clear_interval !== null) // if a timer is already returning don't start another
        return;

    clear_interval = setInterval(function () {
        rec_block.css('background-color', 'red');
        stop_set_time_out = setTimeout(function () {
            rec_block.css('background-color', 'green');
        }, 500)
    }, 1000);
};

function stop_record() {
    alert("Stop record.");
    clearTimeout(stop_set_time_out);
    clearInterval(clear_interval);
    stop_set_time_out = clear_interval = null;
}
```

You can also make your code a bit simpler (by removing the `setTimeout`) to make it easier to debug, like so:

```
//Public Variables.
var clear_interval, isRed = false;

function record_css_effect() {
    if (clear_interval !== null) // if a timer is already returning don't start another
        return;

    clear_interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (isRed) {
            rec_block.css('background-color', 'red');
            isRed = false;
        } else {
            rec_block.css('background-color', 'green');
            isRed = true;
        }
    }, 500);
};

function stop_record() {
    alert("Stop record.");
    clearInterval(clear_interval);
    clear_interval = null;
}?
```

Comment: @Martin Hols     Some error in the second example: 1. if(isRed){isRed =false} so when it comes to the next period, it will go to the else{}
and the in the else{} "isRed = true;" 2. var clear_interval = null is necessary. However, thank you. But I still don't understand the explanation about "only the last interval-id will be stored".
I store clear_interval each time, and clear it each time as I don't need to record. Why should I set the "NULL".

Comment: I fixed the isRed values in the answer, you were right they should have been the other way around. As for the timer, maybe a jsFiddle will better explain it; http://jsfiddle.net/a3jT9/. The null is only set so the `if (clear_interval !== null)` in the `record_css_effect()` function works in all cases. It has no other purpose.